# How to slice a pandas dataframe based on the position after a specified row

Tags: python, pandas

The following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['A', '1', '2', '3', 'B', '4', '5', 'C', '7', '8', '10']})
```

Produces the following dataframe:

```
   col
0    A
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    B
5    4
6    5
7    C
8    7
9    8
10  10
```

I would like to come up with a good, pandas-friendly way of slicing the dataframe based on the occurence of the letters 'A', 'B' or 'C'. The expected result is as follows:

```
   col   col2
1    1      A
2    2      A
3    3      A
5    4      B
6    5      B
8    7      C
9    8      C
10  10      C
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a mask which finds the rows to split.  To create `col2`, boolean index with the mask, reindex with the full original index, forward-fill the missing values.  For `col1`, copy the original `col`.  Then create the final `df` and index with the negation of the mask.

```
mask = df['col'].isin(['A', 'B', 'C']) # could use df['col'].str.isalpha() also
col2 = df['col'][mask].reindex(df.index).ffill()
col1 = df['col']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':col1, 'col2':col2})[~mask]
```

Result (`df`):

```
   col1 col2
1     1    A
2     2    A
3     3    A
5     4    B
6     5    B
8     7    C
9     8    C
10   10    C
```

Answer (score 2):

Just find the string/substring you are looking for in the column, then explode and `ffill` it. You can then just filter out the dataframe where `col` and `col2` have different values.

```py
df['col2'] = df['col'].str.findall('A|B|C').explode().ffill()

df[df['col']!=df['col2']]
```

```py
   col col2
1    1    A
2    2    A
3    3    A
5    4    B
6    5    B
8    7    C
9    8    C
10  10    C
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to form a mask with `isalpha` or not to mark letters, and group by the letter and "its digits" via `cumsum`. Then `transform`ing with `"first"` gives almost `col2` except for repetition for letters, which are dropped with the firstly formed mask:

```
mask = df.col.str.isalpha()
grouper = mask.cumsum()

new_df = df.assign(col2=df.groupby(grouper).transform("first"))[~mask]
```

to get

```
>>> new_df

   col col2
1    1    A
2    2    A
3    3    A
5    4    B
6    5    B
8    7    C
9    8    C
10  10    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needs a clever way of slicing:

- Find all of the letters
- Mask anything that is not a letter as NaN
- Forward fill the column
- Remove the original rows that were letters

```
is_letters = df["col"].str.isalpha()
new_df = df.where(is_letters).ffill().loc[~is_letters]

print(new_df)
   col
1    A
2    A
3    A
5    B
6    B
8    C
9    C
10   C
```